# To prove that a specified element belongs to a set under given conditions.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

Let $S=\{1,2,\cdots ,n\}$ where $n$ is an odd integer. Let $f$ be a function defined on $\{(i,j): i\in S, j \in S\}$ taking values in $S$ such that
$(i) f(s,r)=f(r,s)$ for all $r,s \in S$
$(ii) \{f(r,s): s\in S\}=S$ for all $r\in S$

Show that $\{f(r,r): r\in S\}=S$

My attempt:

Since, $n$ is odd, the set $S$ is non-empty. Now, let the element be $k$. Now, it is obvious that $f(k,k)=f(k,k)$ and $k\in S$, so the first condition is satisfied, and by default the second condition is satisfied too, so can we claim that $\{f(r,r): r\in S\}=S$ from this?

If not then please help me prove it.

Comment: The two conditions $i$ and $ii$ are hypothesis, you know they are satisfied

Comment: @ᛥᛥᛥ does that mean I can conclude?

Comment: No, it means you haven't said anything new. You haven't really used the hypothesis to show $\{f(r,r):r\in S\}=S$.

Comment: @ᛥᛥᛥ okay, so you have any approach in mind?

Comment: As the comment said, the conditions are hypotheses you're assuming, not conclusions you're trying to prove. Have you considered a proof by contradiction? If it's not obvious to you why something is true (or if you just think it's not obvious that there IS anything to prove), then contradiction is usually a good place to start. Ex, assume your k satisfies i and ii but not ... Etc.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $R=\{f(r,r):r\in S\}\subsetneq S$ and let $a\in S\setminus R$. Build the matrix $$F=\begin{pmatrix}
f(1,1) & f(1,2) & \cdots & f(1,n) \\ 
f(2,1) & f(2,2) & \cdots & f(2,n) \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
f(n,1) & f(n,2) & \cdots & f(n,n)
\end{pmatrix}$$ and note what your hypothesis say:

- $i)$ $F$ is a symmetric matrix.
- $ii)$ Every element of $S$ appears exactly once in every row/column of $F$.

Since we're assuming $a$ does not belong to the main diagonal of $F$, (according to $i)$ above) it must be in an even number of entries of $F$, but that's not possible.

Comment: How do you know about the diagonal elements?

Comment: @Hawk I don't understand your question. The set of elements on the main diagonal is $R$.